# Dependency Injection , mocking stuff from external libraries?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I am interested in using Dependency Injection however I am confused as to how I am supposed to deal with external libs that were not designed with DI in mind.

For example, if I have some code that constructs objects that are within the scope of my project I can use an interface and then create mock versions as well as concrete versions of these.

However the same code might also use an external library to write to a database or call an API or whatever. The external library might only provide a concrete implementation of this.

This means that my code will have a mixture of concrete and abstract stuff in it and will force me into testing the external library at the same time as the rest of my code.

Should I be creating wrappers for all the external classes so that I can inject mock versions in? This seems like a lot of work.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example? Do you know that mocking frameworks can create mocks of concrete classes as well?

Comment: It totally depends. If you're testing code that relies on a third-party library, however, your test is already too broad for a unit test and is an integration test. I don't understand why you'd need to create a wrapper for an external class in most cases, though, can't you mock them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do have to create mocks of concrete, third-party dependencies in order to isolate your own units, you can do so very easily using a mocking framework such as [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito) that makes use of instrumentation.

Unit testing should inform and reinforce your design decisions, not drive them, and you should be able to write them quickly to focus most of your efforts on the design and implementation of real code.  Modern frameworks like Mockito make this possible.

Comment: There *is* the concept of Test Driven Design. So I don't totally agree with you.

Comment: It's a fine semantic difference (between my stated view and that of the test-driven design lot) in the use of the word "drive" more than anything.  I occasionally use test-driven development techniques, but I would still consider it more of an "informing" of my design than a driver.  The problem-solution space should be the true driver, testing techniques should be helpful informers.  Of course, I'm sure some poor souls will always disagree with this viewpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can also easily test your code with the Needle Framework - http://needle.spree.de/. It is well integrated with Mockito and EasyMock. Needle reduces the test setup code by analysing dependencies and automatic injection of mock objects.